# mysqli prepared statement - do not update NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a prepared statement to update several fields. I get the data from a formular, but not all fields are required. So it's possible that some fields are not set. I set them default to NULL. Now I don't want to overwrite the old value by NULL. How can I tell MySql not to Update the value if it's NULL?

```
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
UPDATE members SET username=?, email=?,  $password=?, $random_salt=?, level=?, customerID=?, name=?, surname=?, phone=?, quantities=? WHERE id=?
");
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssissss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $level, $customerID, $firstname, $surname, $phone);
$insert_stmt->execute();
```

In my case it's the password and random_salt value that could be NULL. It will be very bad to overwrite the password just by NULL ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your query as follows:

```
UPDATE members SET
    username = IFNULL(?, username),
    email = IFNULL(?, email) -- and so on for all fields
WHERE...
```

It could also be more efficient to check the value of your parameters first, and build the query dynamically, including only fields for which you have a non-null value to update with.

Comment: Dynamically build query for a similar task _may_ defeat _one of_ the benefits of prepared statement: prepare once and execute many times, giving DB software the chance to optimise the process.

Comment: Correct. One must be careful when it comes to optimisation, I will rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET username=?, email=?,  password=IF(LENGTH('?')=0, password, '?'), random_salt=IF(LENGTH('?')=0, random_salt, '?'), level=?, customerID=?, name=?, surname=?, phone=?, quantities=? WHERE id=?");
```

the If condition translates to: 
    IF( < YOUR_CONDITION >, < VALUE_IF_TRUE >, < VALUE_IF_FALSE >).

Answer (score 0):

Read your query fields and data carefuly. Set of fields and set of data in bind are not match.

```
UPDATE members SET username=?, email=?,  $password=?, $random_salt=?, level=?, customerID=?, name=?, surname=?, phone=?, quantities=? WHERE id=?

$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssissss', $username, $email, $level, $customerID, $firstname, $surname, $phone);
```

Your bind list has no: password, random_salt, id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id is PK you can use :

```
INSERT INTO members (
    id,
    username,
    email,
    password,
    random_salt,
    level,
    customerID,
    name,
    surname,
    phone,
    quantities
) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
)   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    username = IF(username <> '',VALUES(username),username),
    email = IF(email <> '',VALUES(email),email),
    password = IF(password <> '',VALUES(password),password)
    ...
```