# Binding fields as values with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP application I am developing. It contains a function that edits a user in the database. The function accepts `false` or a value as its arguments; `false` means that field should be left as is.

Currently, I am using this code:

```php
function edit_user($id, $name = false, $key = false, $mode = false, $notes = false){
    $changes = array();
    $changestr = "";
    $values = array();
    if($name !== false){
        $changes[] = "name=?";
        $values[] = &$name;
    }
    // 3 more identical ifs
    for($i = 0; $i < count($changes); $i++) $changestr .= 's';
    $changestr .= 'i';
    $values[] = &$id;
    array_unshift($values, $changestr);
    $query = $db_connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET " . join(",", $changes) . " WHERE userId=?");
    call_user_func_array(array($query, "bind_param"), $values);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->affected_rows >= 1;
}
```

(Yes, I know the values are not escaped, I do it elsewhere.)

Something, however, is not working here. What I'd like to do to improve it is just have the query like this:

```sql
UPDATE users SET name=?,password=?,mode=?,notes=? WHERE userId=?
```

And then just bind the field name if I need to leave it as is. What I'm asking, is this possible to do with mysqli? Or does the prepared statement break my idea?

**UPDATE:** What I mean is can I use mysqli like this:

1. Take this query:

   ```sql
   UPDATE users SET name=?,password=?,mode=?,notes=? WHERE userId=?
   ```
2. Update some values but leave some as is, like this:

   ```sql
   UPDATE users SET name='Test',password=password,mode=mode,notes='asdf' WHERE userId=723
   ```

Comment: Please, can you explain better what's your question?

Comment: I guess you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102861/mysqli-prepared-statement-do-not-update-null-values

Comment: @gafreax Updated. Maybe it's clearer now.

Answer (score -1):

@Pietu1998 Yes it's more clear.

The answer it's simple: you cant'd do that. You can however get the same result with some tricks as creating some functions like this

```
function buildSQLComparison($name,$value=false) {
   return $name . '=' . ($value)?$value : $name;
}

function buildSQLComparisonForBinding($name,$value=false) {
   return $name . '=' . ($value)?'?' : $name;
}
```

and call it:

```
$sqlNamePart = buildSQLComparisonForBinding($$name,$name);
$sqlPasswordPart = buildSQLComparisonForBinding($$password,$password);
$param = array($sqlNamePart,$sqlPasswordPart );
$query = $db_connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET " . join(",",$param);
```

I hope this can be useful for you.

PS: I suggest you to avoid to use reference to var (es:&$name;)

**UPDATE**:

read at us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, you can do simply build a query   doing that:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET name=?,password=?,mode=?,notes=? WHERE userId=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', 
  $name?$name:$$name, 
  $password?$password:$$password, 
  $mode?$mode:$$mode, 
  $notes?$notes:$$notes);
```

I hope this can be useful

Comment: Why it's not useful? can I help you better?

Comment: @Pietu1998 Yes no problem: I see that someone mark my answer as no useful, so I asked why!!

Comment: What I was looking for is to use the binding mechanic to bind the field's name to the `?`. This would allow for `name=?` to be transformed to either `name='foo'` or `name=name` depending on the input.

Comment: like you can see at http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php you can do simply a query like this: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code?$code:$$code, $language?$language:$$language, $official?$official:$$official, $percent?$percent:$$percent);`